# Regex to Add Trailing Slash to URL Unless the URL Ends in a File Extension

Tags: wordpress, redirect, url-rewriting, regexp-replace

I'm currently trying to get a WordPress site (using the Redirection plugin) to always add a trailing slash to any URL without one, but only if the URL doesn't end in a slash already or a file extension (so images, .php files/pages, etc. aren't affected).

e.g. `www.mysite.com/page` becomes `www.mysite.com/page/`, but `www.mysite.com/page/` and `www.mysite.com/file.php` are left alone.

I was able to get the first half working (forcing a trailing slash if it doesn't already end in one), but I'm struggling to add the extra condition.

This is what I currently have:

Source URL: `/([^\/]+)$`

Target URL: `/$1/`

Using .htaccess, etc. isn't an option unfortunately. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there can not be a dot in the part after the last `/` then you can add it to the negated character class.

If the [delimiter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) is not a `/` then you don't have to escape it in the pattern.

```
/([^/.]+)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/unnmVV/1)

Comment: Both this and horcrux's solutions worked for me. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you need, you can add `(?!.*\.)` (not followed by a period), or `(?!.*\.php$)` (not followed by a php extension), or `(?!.*\.(?:php|jpg)$)` (not followed by a php or jpg extension), ecc.

Full examples:

```
\/(?!.*\.)[^\/]+$
\/(?!.*\.php$)[^\/]+$
\/(?!.*\.(?:php|jpg)$)[^\/]+$
```

In these examples the matching group is not necessary, so you can replace with `$0\/`.

See working demos [here](https://regex101.com/r/MgC3ae/1) and [here](https://regex101.com/r/Kt0t7W/3).

Comment: Both this and The fourth bird's solutions worked for me. Thank you for the help!